# integrability question, lower\upper integral and the lower\upper Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-sum

> Define a function $g : [0, 1] \mapsto \mathbb R$ by the following formula:
>
> $$g(x)=\begin{cases}-1,&x\in \mathbb{Q}\\x^3-x,&x\not\in \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
>
> (a) What is $\underline{I}^b_a(g)$
>   ? Justify your answer from the definition.
>
> (b) What is $\overline{I}^b_a(g)$
>   ? Justify your answer from the definition.
>
> (c) Is $g$ integrable on $[0, 1]$? Justify your answer

---

What I tried so far:

Let $p$ be any partition

Let $p_n=\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ 
(equal sub-intervals)

s.t. for each index $i_1,i_2 \in [1,n]\cap \mathbb{N}$ have $\triangle x_{i_1}=\triangle x_{i_2}$

(a)

\begin{align}
\underline{I}^b_a(g)
& =\sup \{\text{lower sum of }g(x)\}
\\
& =\lim _{\|p\|\to 0}L_p(g)\tag{*}
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\underline{S^*_{p_{n}}}(g) \Leftrightarrow =\lim _{n\to \infty }L_{p_n}(g) \tag{**}
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{i=1}^n\:\frac{b-a}{n}\inf\limits _{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}g(x) \tag{***}
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{i=1}^n\:\frac{b-a}{n}(-1)
\\
& =a-b
\end{align}

(b)

\begin{align}
\overline{I}^b_a(g)
& = \inf \{\text{upper sum of }g(x)\} \\
& =\lim _{\|p\|\to 0}U_p(g) \tag{*}
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\overline{S^*_{p_{n}}}(g) \Leftrightarrow =\lim _{n\to \infty }U_{p_n}(g) \tag{**}
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{i=1}^n\:\frac{b-a}{n}\sup\limits_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}g(x) \tag{***}
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{i=1}^n\:\frac{b-a}{n}\sup\limits_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}x^3-x
\\
& =\overline{I}^b_a(x^3-x)=\underline{I}^b_a(x^3-x)
\\
& = {I}^b_a(x^3-x)
\\
& =\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{i=1}^n\:\frac{b-a}{n}(x^3_i-x_i)
\\
& \vdots
\\
& =-\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{b^4}{4}+\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{b^2}{2}
\end{align}

(c)No, since lower integral and upper integral are not equal.

---

Question:

1.From $(*)$ to $(**)$, is it right to say that when $\|P\|$ approaches $0$ for lower Darboux sum that is same as the lower Riemann sum when n approaches infinite? And the same for upper Darboux sums?

2.From $(**)$ to $(***)$, did I write the right definitions?

3.Is there any other metheds?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update1

For my first question, I think Upper/Lower Riemann sum is same as Upper/Lower Darboux sum, that notation $\overline{S^*_{p}}(g)$/$\underline{S^*_{p}}(g)$ means same thing as $U_p(g)$/$L_p(g)$, but is it valid to change $\|P\|\rightarrow 0$ to $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $p$ to $p_n$?
For my second question, the definition should be right.

---

Update2

Step in Q1 and Q2 are both valid, I just wondering if there is other methed to do this.

Comment: What are $a,b$? Is it $[a,b]\subseteq [0,1]$? How do you know that you can calculate the upper and lower integral using only equidistant subdivisions? One indeed gets $\underline{I}^b_a(g) = b-a$ when considering all subsivisions, but you only got $\overline{I}^b_a(g) \le -\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{b^4}{4}+\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{b^2}{2}$. Maybe by picking differently spaced $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ you can further reduce the sum.

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Comment: Calculus in One Dimension  Volume 2 by Tyler Holden

Comment: Which is the difference between $L_P(g)$ and $\underline{S^*_P}(g)$ ?

Comment: I think Upper/Lower Riemann sum is same as Upper/Lower Darboux sum, that notation $\overline{S^*_{p}}(g)$/$\underline{S^*_{p}}(g)$ means same thing as $U_p(g)$/$L_p(g)$, but $p$ and $p_n$ are different, please check my updates @ Tony Piccolo